# Remove gif,png images from html content using preg replace pattern

Tags: html, image, preg-replace

I have a content i want to remove only gif and png images from my HTML content with using preg replace pattern

For example

```
$str='<div>
<img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/test/my.jpeg" width="1" height="1" border="0" />

In a 1999 Food section story, we found this recipe for Bacchus\' Wine Punch. It serves more if you top the punch with club soda or ginger ale, which of course we would advise.

Remember, Carnival season is a marathon, not a sprint.

<strong>Bacchus\' Wine Punch </strong>

<em>Serves 8 (more with club soda or ginger ale)</em>

<span>2 limes, sliced</span>
<img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/test/my.GIF" width="1" height="1" border="0" />

4 oranges, halved and sliced

1 green apple, unpeeled and thinly sliced

1/4 cup confectioners\' sugar, or to taste

<img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/test/my.jpeg" width="1" height="1" border="0" />

2 bottles dry red or white wine

1/2 cup brandy or Cointreau

Club soda or ginger ale, optional

<img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/test/my.png" width="1" height="1" border="0" />

Place sliced lemon, orange and apple in large pitcher; sprinkle with confectioners\' sugar and add wine, stirring and pressing fruit until sugar dissolves. Add brandy and chill mixture well before serving over ice. Top with an equal amount of club soda or ginger ale, if desired.

</div>

<img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/test/my.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />';

$str = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>(?:<\/img>)?)/i', '', $str);  // this is remove all images tab but i want to remove only gif and png images

echo $str;
```

Comment: `preg_replace('/(what)[have]\y\o\u{tried}/?');`

Comment: thanks for posting but i want exactly pattern like removing gif and png images like...    preg_replace('#<img[^>]*?src="(.*?(gif|jpeg|jpg|png))".?>#i', '', $str);

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
$str = preg_replace('~<img .*?\.(gif|png)".*?/>~sim', '', $str);

print $str;
```

Explanation of REGEX:

```
<img    .*?   \.(gif|png)"   .*?   />
  ^      ^          ^         ^    ^
  1      2          3         4    5
```

1. Look for the opening image tag, followed by a space.
2. Look for anything up until a dot followed by a "gif" or "png"
3. Look for a literal dot, followed by "gif" or "png" followed by quotes.
4. Look for anything up until the closing "/>"
5. Look for the closing "/>"

Comment: But actual regex that i want is $regex = "/src=[\"']?([^\"']?.*(png|gif))[\"']?/i";